# Privilege for CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

Why am I unable to create this aggregate function?

As far as I can tell, I've granted the appropriate privileges (`CREATE ROUTINE` and `ALTER ROUTINE`) both on `*.*` and on my database (`peacock`):

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host, Create_priv, Create_routine_priv, Alter_routine_priv FROM mysql.user WHERE user='glpy';
+------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| User | Host      | Create_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv |
+------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| glpy | localhost | Y           | Y                   | Y                  |
+------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+

mysql> SELECT User, Host, db, Create_priv, Create_routine_priv, Alter_routine_priv FROM mysql.db WHERE user='glpy';
+------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| User | Host      | db      | Create_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv |
+------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| glpy | localhost | peacock | N           | Y                   | Y                  |
+------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

However, when I try to create the function, I get `Access denied ... to database 'mysql'`:

```
mysql> use peacock;
mysql> CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION coverage RETURNS INT SONAME 'my-library.so';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'glpy'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

In particular:

- Why is access required to the `mysql` table to create the aggregate function?
- Given that I have granted the privileges on `*.*`, why is access denied?
- I also tried granting the privileges on `mysql`, but access was still denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE [AGGREGATE] FUNCTION function_name 
RETURNS {STRING|INTEGER|REAL|DECIMAL}
SONAME shared_library_name;
```

This is the declaration for a [**User Defined Function**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-functions.html), which appears to be what you are trying to install.  This is *not* declaring a [Stored Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html).  `CREATE FUNCTION` has [two different uses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function.html) in MySQL.  This is one of them.

For this to work:

- you do not need the `CREATE ROUTINE` privilege
- it does not matter what database you're in, because User-Defined Functions, unlike stored functions, are global in scope.  They extend MySQL functionality in a way that is analogous to its built-in aggregate functions, like `AVG()` and `SUM()` and `MIN()` and `MAX()`.
- you cannot specify a database as part of the function declaration
- the following is the requirement that you are missing:

> <sup>13.7.3.1. CREATE FUNCTION Syntax for User-Defined Functions</sup>
>
> To create a function, you must have the `INSERT` privilege for the mysql database. This is necessary because `CREATE FUNCTION` adds a row to the `mysql.func` system table that records the function's name, type, and shared library name.
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function-udf.html</sup>

If you don't have this privilege, the function will have to be installed by someone who holds this privilege, or it will need to be granted to you.  You can't grant it to yourself.

Comment: Of course, you also need `DELETE` in order to `DROP` the function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html):

> CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION require the CREATE ROUTINE privilege.

Make sure the privilege is on the database that you are trying to use. When you run `CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION coverage RETURNS INT SONAME 'my-library.so';`, you are trying to create the function in the `mysql` database (that is, the system database that is actually named `mysql`), so you need the `CREATE ROUTINE` privilege on that database. If you are trying to create it in some other database, run a `USE my_database` command or modify your syntax:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION my_database.coverage RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'my-library.so';
```

If you are in a shared environment (pretty much anything other than a VPS or dedicated server), you probably don't have access to do anything to the `mysql` database and never will. So, create the function in your own database.

**Edit:** `INT` should be `INTEGER`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but these privileges are already granted and I'm still access denied.

Comment: See edits above; make sure you are running your command against the right database.

Comment: Hmmm I tried `CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION my_database.coverage...` but got a syntax error. It is a dedicated server, and I can confirm that I'm "using" my database. I don't understand why it's trying to create it in the mysql database.

Comment: It should be `INTEGER`, not `INT`, [according to the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function-udf.html). I missed this before; sorry. I have updated my answer.